# How to update value in a nested Immutable map

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, immutable-collections

I am new to immutable.js and trying to figure out a way to update a nested map

Here is my object

```
let state = OrderedMap({
    'name': Map({ id: 'name', hint: 'Search by name', value: '' }),
    'job': Map({ id: 'job', hint: 'Search by job title', value: ''}),
    'state':  Map({ id: 'state', hint: 'Search by state', value: ''})
});
```

I am trying to set value of the 'name' object using a setIn function

```
state.setIn(['name', 'value'], 'Test');
```

The value is not getting updated as expected. Am I missing anything here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setIn` doesn't mutate the original `state`, however it returns you another one so you would essentially have

```
state = state.setIn(['name', 'value'], 'Test');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used immutable, but it looks to me like the docs are saying you want something more like:

```
setIn(state, ['name', 'value'], 'Test');
```

Where you are passing in the collection rather than running a function on it with a dot operator.

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/setIn

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mutating the state you can use `setIn` as this will return you a fresh copy instead , So you can do something like :

```
state = state.setIn(['name', 'value'], 'Test');
```

You can read more on [Facebook Github](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/setIn)